# SQL search and JavaScript .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, postgresql

I have been googling around to try to solve my issue without success.

First I understand that ".map" is a method for an array, but the variable "restaurants" is in my useState. So I didn't understand why I receive the error **"TypeError: restaurants.map is not a function".**

I'm trying to implement a search function in a PERN app that I've been studying. This is my Search component.

Please help me understand what might be wrong. This is the full [repo](https://github.com/drrh12/pratika_2021/blob/main/README.md) in case this piece of code is not enough.

**Search component:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Search() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([]);

  const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/restaurants/?name=${name}`
      );

      const parseResponse = await response.json();

      setRestaurants(parseResponse);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mb-4">
        <form className="form-row" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Search"
            className="form-control"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <table className="table my-5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Restaurant</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {restaurants.map((restaurants) => (
              <tr key={restaurants.restaurants_id}>
                <td>{restaurants.name}</td>
                <td>{restaurants.location}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        {restaurants.length === 0 && <p>No Results Found</p>}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

**File in server.js:**

```
app.get("/api/v1/restaurants", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name } = req.query;

    const restaurants = await pool.query(
      "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE name || ' ' ||",
      [`%${name}%`]
    );

    res.json(restaurants.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the content of `parseResponse`?

Comment: Should be what it is in my Postgres database. The name being fetched from the api.

Comment: I think that you have to handle your empty restaurant array until its state gets updated from the HTTP response. can you try changing this in your react code -   `<tbody> {  restaurants.length > 0  &&  restaurants.map((restaurants) => (...) } <tbody>`

Comment: Cool. With this I got ride of the .map is not a function but the SQL doesn't return the filter with the search.

`{restaurants.length > 0 &&
              restaurants.map((restaurants) => (
                <tr key={restaurants.restaurants_id}>
                  <td>{restaurants.name}</td>
                  <td>{restaurants.location}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}`

Comment: can you do the console.log() of your `select * from ...` query and try running that plain query on postgre SQL interface? or paste it here so that we can figure out the syntactical error, if any.

Comment: This query would be correct?

const restaurants = await pool.query(
      "SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE name || ' ' ||",
      [`%${name}%`]
    );

Comment: Can you just `console.log("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE name || ' ' ||",
      [`%${name}%`])` this? And paste it here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234921/discussion-between-mukund-and-flavio-andrade).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the `javascript.map`is not a function error in your react code you have to replace `tbody` in your react code in the following way to handle your empty restaurants array until its state gets updated from the HTTP response.

```js
<tbody>
{
    restaurants.length > 0 && restaurants.map((restaurants) => (
    <tr key={restaurants.restaurants_id}>
        <td>{restaurants.name}</td>
        <td>{restaurants.location}</td>
    </tr>
    ))
}
</tbody>
```

Your another question related to not getting response from the backend for your postgre SQL query, you must `console.log()` your query and try running it on SQL interface to find the syntactical errors.